# line-clamp is not working on Firefox?

Tags: css

I have one slider tab. I am trying to display only 3 line with ellipsis. The given CSS is working well in Chrome, but it is not working in Firefox. Please suggest a better way.

```
.ui-slider-tabs-list li a {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
             -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
             -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -moz-box; 
             -moz-line-clamp: 3;
             -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: `line-clamp` is a Webkit extension that is not supported by other browsers. See [this page](http://www.cssmojo.com/line-clamp_for_non_webkit-based_browsers/).

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
position:relative;
line-height:20px;
/* 3 times the line-height to show 3 lines */
height:60px;
}
```

you can set the height to hide the overflow for Firefox

Comment: This answer does not address the desired effect of multi-line text with ellipsized overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at [line-clamp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-clamp). It's a node package but should still work as it is in your browser. Works in Firefox. It's lightweight and has 0 dependencies.